# Stacktrace from Camel Context onException

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to retrieve the stacktrace from the onException handler in Apache Camel:

```
   <onException>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <handled>
                <constant>true</constant>
            </handled>

            <setHeader headerName="exception">
                <simple>${exception}</simple>
            </setHeader>
   </onException>
```

However, the above only shows the exception rather than the entire stacktrace.

I understand that Camel stores the caught exception as a property on the Exchange with the key: Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, but how can this be retrieved from the camel context routes file ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use exception.stacktrace to get the stacktrace. See the variables listed in the table at this page: http://camel.apache.org/simple

```
<simple>${exception.stacktrace}</simple>
```

There is also a ${exception.message} to refer to the exception message itself.

Comment: Thanks, this worked a treat. Creating a bean was the other alternative I had in mind.

Comment: Thanks Claus. Just a question on this - is it also possible to use `exception.class` ?

Comment: Ok, I answered this - yes, it is possible. But it's almost better to just use `exception` in the simple expression, since that gives you the class name and the message.

Comment: Often camel puts exception into CamelExceptionCaught property, how to print stacktrace in this case?